# Failed readahead on ifile EBADF: Bad file descriptor while performing matrix addition

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to write a code in Apache Pig for matrix addition.

```
matrixM = LOAD 'Mmatrix.txt' USING PigStorage (',') AS (i,j,v);
matrixN = LOAD 'Nmatrix.txt' USING PigStorage (',') AS (i,j,v);
unionres = UNION matrixM, matrixN;
DUMP unionres;
res = GROUP unionres BY (i,j);
DUMP res;
ILLUSTRATE res;
final_res = FOREACH res GENERATE group.$0 AS i, group.$1 AS j, SUM(unionres.v) AS v;
DUMP final_res;
```

I am getting following exception while running the code in local mode.

```
org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool - Failed readahead on ifile
EBADF: Bad file descriptor
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posix_fadvise(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX$CacheManipulator.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool$ReadaheadRequestImpl.run(ReadaheadPool.java:208)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anybody please explain me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually above message is WARN and actual error message is shown afterwards.  I've only seen this type of WARN message when disk is bad or full.  Any chances your local /tmp is full?